# Good reference for Enterprise Service Bus

Tags: c#, esb

I am just getting started with ESB, I am currently reading the code for [rhino-esb](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-service-bus), to see how it is implemented.

Are there any good resources (i.e. books, videos) for beginners to get started with ESB? I am also trying to understand the difference between EAI and ESB.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This website (http://www.eaipatterns.com/) has good information about EAI.

Comment: awesome! I actually bought the book, didn't realize that the author covers all the aspects. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can start looking at [Apache Synapse](http://synapse.apache.org/) Enterprise Service Bus (ESB). It has so many [samples](http://synapse.apache.org/userguide/samples.html), which will help you to understand ESB features.

Comment: Thanks for the link Isuru, I was looking for a .NET implementation, Synapse is in Java which is not too far from C#. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Any reasons why you are looking for C# (or .NET specific)  implementation?

Comment: ya cause I work with C# have never used Java. Right now I am also learning C# so it would be too much to learn Java.

Comment: I think it's okay to use any ESB for your needs and you can have your services in C#. ESB will do its job and you won't have to worry about its implementation.

Comment: you are absolutely right, but I want to learn how the ESB is implemented, which is why I am looking for a .NET Implementation.

Comment: That's really good. Like you said in first comment, you can start looking at Apache Synapse and you will be able to understand Java code as you are already familiar with C#